# How to read column names of a multicolumn ListView control?

Tags: c#, listview, multiple-columns

What is the best way to find the names of the columns of a ListView?

I converted a DataTable to a List using a procedure I found on this forum, but I cannot make it to put the Id column first, especially because not all of my DataTables have a column "Id".

I can search in collection listView.Columns.ToString() but the format I am seeing is:

"ColumnHeader: Text: Id"

which I have to parse to find the proper name "Id".
This does not look like the spirit of C#.

I also tried: `listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems["Id"]`
but that does not compile.

---

Ok Here is the complete code.
The exact problem is that the user selects a row in the listView with Courier Names and Ids, but it could also be Ids and Names, in that order. The fastest way to find the Id of the selected courier would be:

```
ListViewItem si = listCouriers.SelectedItems[0];
CourierId = si.SubItems["Id"].Text;
```

but that does not work. The hardcoded way would be this, but I cannot guarantee that some day the wrong column will be used:

```
ListViewItem si = listCouriers.SelectedItems[0];
CourierId = si.SubItems[1].Text;
```

Using @HuorSwords method leads to this not-so-simple solution, which works for me, but depends on the reasonable assumption that the order of columns in the `ColumnHeaderCollection` corresponds to the display on the form:

```
ListViewItem si = listCouriers.SelectedItems[0];
string CourierId = null;
int icol = 0;
foreach (ColumnHeader header in listCouriers.Columns)
{
    if (header.Text == "Id")
    {
        CourierId = si.SubItems[icol].Text;
        break;
    }
    icol++;
}
```

Comment: __NOTE:__ The OP title explicitly asks about the __Name__ property, which is empty due to a MS bug.  And yet you have accepted an answer which  only gives the __Text__..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `listView.Columns` is of type `ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection`, then it contains `ColumnHeader` objects.

The `ColumnHeader.Text` contains the column title, so you can check for concrete column with:

```
foreach (ColumnHeader header in listView.Columns)
{
      if (header.Text == "Id")
      {
           // Do something...
      }
}
```

I don't know if is the best approach, but you don't need to parse the results to find "Id" value...

**UPDATE**

Also, have you tried to reference it with the `String` indexer? > `listView.Columns["Id"]`

Comment: Thanks! It sounds simple, but I hadn't thought of looking at the `ColumnHeaders`, while looking at `ListViewItem  listView.SelectedItems[0]`. But I had to change `var` to `ColumnHeader` to make it possible to use `.Text`.

Comment: The question now is if the order of the `.ColumnHeaderCollection` is the same as what I see on the form. Most logically it is, I will try this out.

Comment: @HenriqueC. header is of type 'ColumnHeader' and, as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.text(v=vs.110).aspx) says, the 'Text' property exist for this class.

Comment: @HenriqueC. then the answer is still valid. ;)

Comment: @HuorSwords yes it is but change var to ColumnHeader, please.

Comment: __NOTE:__ The OP title explicitly ask about the __Name__ property, which is empty due to a MS bug. This only gives the __Text__..

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
private ColumnHeader GetColumn(string Text)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Items.Count; j++)
            if (listView1.Items[j].SubItems.Count - 1 >= i)
                if (listView1.Items[j].SubItems[i].Text == Text)
                    return listView1.Columns[i];
    return null;
}
```

just give item text to this code and get everything you want of a column.

Enjoy ;)