# How to remove columns from ListView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm new with `ListView` and encountered a small problem :

I have a `ListView`in `WinForm` which I fill it line after line with many columns (about 15) , later on I have an option to save `ListView` to `CSV` . 
what I want is a way to let the user delete unwanted columns from `ListView` .

My function to create the columns at first

```
    private void checkAddListBoxColumns(DomainLayer.ScriptLogic.session sessionToAdd)
    {
        if (IsResultLogListViewFirstRun)
        {
            IsResultLogListViewFirstRun = false;
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Clear();
            });

            foreach (var item in sessionToAdd.comments.Keys)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Add(item);
                });
            }
            McsTableRow mcsTR = new McsTableRow();
            Type t = mcsTR.GetType();
            foreach (/*PropertyInfo*/FieldInfo info in t.GetFields())
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Add(info.Name+" 1");
                });
            }
            foreach (FieldInfo info in t.GetFields())
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Add(info.Name+" 2");
                });
            }
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Add("Effective PHY Rate");
            });
            //...more of the same
        }
        else
        {
            //?
        }
    }
```

later I add line like

```
            private OnSessionToAdd()
            {
            foreach (string key in sessionToAdd.comments.Keys)
            {
                item.SubItems.Add(sessionToAdd.comments[key]);
            }

            Type t = sessionToAdd.CurrentMCSCheck.firstMcsRow.GetType();

            foreach (FieldInfo info in t.GetFields())
            {
                string x = info.GetValue(sessionToAdd.CurrentMCSCheck.firstMcsRow) as string;
                item.SubItems.Add(x);
            }

            t = sessionToAdd.CurrentMCSCheck.secondMcsRow.GetType();

            foreach (FieldInfo info in t.GetFields())
            {
                string x = info.GetValue(sessionToAdd.CurrentMCSCheck.secondMcsRow) as string;
                item.SubItems.Add(x);
            }

            item.SubItems.Add(sessionToAdd.CurrentMCSCheck.EffectivePHYRate);

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
             ResultsLogTab_ListView.Items.Add(item);
            });
            }
```

What i need is a way to get all names of columns and than delete columns by name or some kind of IndexOf(name)

please point me to the right direction

**EDIT**

just to clearfy I dont to hide columns (settings width = 0) I want to delete them 
to help you understand my point I've added the way I save the `ListView`
the way I save to CSV :

```
public StringBuilder ListViewToCSV(ListView listView, string filePath, bool includeHidden)
{
    //make header string
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    WriteCSVRow(result, listView.Columns.Count, i => includeHidden || listView.Columns[i].Width > 0, i => listView.Columns[i].Text);

    //export data rows
    foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView.Items)
        WriteCSVRow(result, listView.Columns.Count, i => includeHidden || listView.Columns[i].Width > 0, i => listItem.SubItems[i].Text);

    return result;

}

private static void WriteCSVRow(StringBuilder result, int itemsCount, Func<int, bool> isColumnNeeded, Func<int, string> columnValue)
{
    bool isFirstTime = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
    {
        if (!isColumnNeeded(i))
            continue;

        if (!isFirstTime)
            result.Append(",");
        isFirstTime = false;

        result.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\"", columnValue(i)));
    }
    result.AppendLine();
}
```

than just save `StringBuilder`

Comment: Is this WPF? WinForms?

Comment: soory , it is winform --> Edited question

Comment: Best question ever :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reference the column by name.

```
var columnToRemove = ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns["Name Of Column"];
```

and then remove it

```
ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Remove(columnToRemove);
```

This is all documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnheadercollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a great resource.

### Update

With regards to saving/loading from CSV let's say you have a `List<string>` of column names (obtained from said CSV file) you want to keep then you can use LINQ to find the columns that do not match, and then iterate over the result to remove them.

```
using System.Linq;

...

var columnNames = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

var columnsToDelete = ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Where(c => !columnNames.Contains(c.Name));

foreach(var column in columnsToDelete)
{
     ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Remove(column);
}
```

Comment: +1 your update is Great !! can you please show How can I get the names of columns  of the ListView

Comment: Fixed link. Do you mean the names of the columns of the `ListView` or the names from the CSV?

Comment: names of the columns from ListView --> I think I have an answer for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985240/how-to-read-column-names-of-a-multicolumn-listview-control

Comment: `ColumnHeader` has a property called `Name`. Once again this is [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader)